# Is it possible to make a circle without using .arc() or any other HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to experiment with the canvas in HTML, and when I make a circle using .arc() I don't know how to get all its points. Anyone know how?

Comment: Have you looked at this [**Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550278/how-to-calculate-the-exact-point-position-of-the-beginning-and-end-of-the-arc#answer-14550347) Maybe this could lead you in the direction you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a circle and get it's points you may do something like this:

```js
let c = document.getElementById("circle");
let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
let cw = c.width = 250;
let ch = c.height = 200;
let cx = cw / 2,
  cy = ch / 2;
  //the array of points
  let points = []


ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.strokeStyle = "#64b150";

//circle's radius
let r = 75;

ctx.beginPath();
for (let a = 0; a < 2*Math.PI; a+=.1) {
  let o = {}//a point on the circle
  o.x = cx + r * Math.cos(a);
  o.y = cy + r * Math.sin(a);
  points.push(o);
  ctx.lineTo(o.x, o.y)
  }
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<canvas id="circle"></canvas>
```

As Kaiido is commenting you mat need to choose a different increment instead of .1: `for (let a = 0; a < 2*Math.PI; a+= increment) {`

Comment: Thanks. I was using it for a [beta project](https://github.com/SciPred/SCIJS-Alpha).

Comment: If I may, 0.1π sounds quite arbitrary, not that it's bad per se, but there should probably be a note about it, especially about the fact it may not look well on large circles

Comment: I agree. You may need to choose a different increment.

Answer (score 0):

Using svg in html, for exmaple:

circle image:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
</svg>
```

You can also change the radius and other details.
See this link: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

To render an approximated circle, and acquire the points of that circle, you could draw a series of line segments in a circular pattern line so:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

/* Center and radius of circle */
const centerX = 50;
const centerY = 50;
const radius = 25;

/* Array containing your points */
const points = [];

/* Configure line rendering and start drawing a path */
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.beginPath();

/* Iterate each side and calculate the position of it's starting point */
for (let i = 0, sides = 50; i < sides; i ++) {
  
  const angle = (i / sides) * 2 * Math.PI;
  const x = centerX + radius * Math.cos(angle);
  const y = centerY + radius * Math.sin(angle);
  
  points.push({ x, y });
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  }
  
/* Complete path and render as stroke */
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();

console.log(points);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: arc should internally calls ellipse... And this doesn't answer the question, only its title.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for the feedback - updated my answer to better suit the question body rather than title :)